# Access JSON in PHP Foreach

Tags: php, json

I couldn't insert json data to my PHP function.I have below json data in posts.json file:

> NOT: a1,a11 etc. are only sample so please don't give suggestion about
> its logic

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "post_name": "a1",
      "post_title": "a11",
      "_is_location": "a111",
      "_hook": "a1111"
    },
    {
      "post_name": "a2",
      "post_title": "a22",
      "_is_location": "a222",
      "_hook": "a2222"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have below PHP code snippet:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(__DIR__ . '/posts.json', true);
foreach($jsonDecode['posts'] as $post_json) {
    //create a variable to specify the details of page
    $post = array(
        'post_name' => $post_json['post_name'],
        'post_content'   => 'This is a example content', //content of page
        'post_title'     => $post_json['post_title'], //title of page
```

normally, my PHP function works but when I changed text with my PHP variables for json, it doesn't work.

if I use my function like this:

```
 'post_name' => 'example name',
```

it works.but with below, it doesn't work:

```
 'post_name' => $post_json['post_name'],
```

PHP error from Wordpress log file:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Do you get error messages? Its not completely clear what you problem is

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is no error.normally, it must add new posts by "foreach", but it doesn't

Comment: You could do a var_dump($jsonDecode); var_dump($post_json); to verify that what you expect is what you get.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am sorry for wrong information.I checked it again, and I pasted error to question, can you look at again?

Comment: that look like the `json_decode()` failed, better check the file actually looks like you think and that it is on that path and that it is valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that if you add the lines...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

...to the top of your document you'll get notices similar to:

> Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in..
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

This is because `json_decode` accepts as `string` as it's first parameter and you're supplying it with a file location...

Change:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(__DIR__ . '/posts.json', true);
```

To:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/posts.json'), true);
```

...and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/posts.json'), true);
foreach($jsonDecode['posts'] as $post_json) {
    //create a variable to specify the details of page
    $post = array(
        'post_name' => $post_json['post_name'],
        'post_content'   => 'This is a example content', //content of page
        'post_title'     => $post_json['post_title'], //title of page
    );
}
```

This code works, but I assume you are only getting 1 occurance in the `$post` array.

So change this line

```
$post = array(
```

To

```
$post[] = array(
```

Now you will get all the occurances

Comment: I know, like I said, missed that

Comment: You are right about the `$post[]`, it will overwrite otherwise! (I assumed it was a typo as he said it worked "normally")